# Update and filter pivot with VBA - Wildcard filter

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I want to clear the prevoius filter on pivotfield ***Invoicenr***, update a pivot table, and not show certain items.
I want to show Everything but the items that have a ***Invoicenr*** that begins with **PO*** (seems that * can't be used in VBA?).
Besides this I want to see everything else and the ***Invoicenr*** that starts with **PO** and contains **OH**.

See my attempt below:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll    
      'Worksheets("Pivot").Select
      'ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PIVOT1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PIVOT1").PivotFields("Invoicenr"). _
        ClearLabelFilters              
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PIVOT1").PivotFields("invoicenr")
        .PivotItems("PO").Visible = False         
    End With        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the conditions correctly, this should get you the results you want for the first case...

**Show All Items except ones that begin with "PO" :**

```
Sub ShowAllButPO()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim pvtItem As PivotItem

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables("PIVOT1")
    Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Invoicenr")

    pvtTable.RefreshTable

    pvtTable.ClearAllFilters

    For Each pvtItem In pvtField.PivotItems
        If Left(UCase(pvtItem), 2) = "PO" Then
            pvtItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And this should cover the second condition...

**Show All Items in "invoicenr" that start with "PO" *and* also contain "OH" :**

```
Sub ShowOnlyPO()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
    Dim pvtField As PivotField
    Dim pvtItem As PivotItem

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables("PIVOT1")
    Set pvtField = pvtTable.PivotFields("Invoicenr")

    pvtTable.RefreshTable

    pvtTable.ClearAllFilters

    For Each pvtItem In pvtField.PivotItems
        If Left(UCase(pvtItem), 2) = "PO" And InStr(UCase(pvtItem), "OH") > 0 Then
            pvtItem.Visible = True
        Else
            pvtItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm less sure about what you wanted for the second condition. Your wording "i want to see Everything else and the invoicenr that starts with PO and contains "OH"" wasn't completely clear to me.

If you could clarify what you mean by "**Everything else** and invoicenr that starts with PO.. etc etc" then I can update my code if needed.

Also, if those two code blocks end up getting you what you want, then you could just assign each macro to its own button in your worksheet. That way, you could just toggle the two scenarios without having to open the VBEditor to run the code.  If you are unsure how to do this, check out this **[link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

Comment: The 'Left(UCase(pvtItem), 2)' snippet is what was missing on my logic. Once I saw how you matched the values it was eazy pizie.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
   Sub Except_PO()

      Dim var As Variant

      var = "PO*"

     ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotFields("Invoicenr").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotFields("Invoicenr").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotEqual, Value1:=var

   End Sub


  Sub POwithOH()

   Dim var As Variant

    var = "PO*OH*"

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotFields("Invoicenr").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot1").PivotFields("Invoicenr").PivotFilters. _
      Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=var


  End Sub
```

Then make 2 command buttons with this code

filtering All EXCEPT PO

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       Call Except_PO

     End Sub
```

Filtering data starting with PO and contains OH

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
       Call POwithOH

     End Sub
```

So if you click CommandButton1, your pivot will filter those data that don't start with PO.
And when you click CommandButton2, your pivot will filter all data that starts with PO AND contains OH.