# Set Pivot Table Page filter with wildcard

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to set a Page filter in a Pivot Table, using string "Test" as base of search, so that it returns anything that contains that piece of String on it. I tried using `*` as wildcard for the string, but it returns an error.

I have been able to do this for Pivot Filters (columns/rows), but seems that Page filters (the ones on top/outside of the pivot table) use a different method or syntax.

I've tried searching in other threads and did not find an answer that fits my needs. Here is part of the code:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim TextFilter As String

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Title")
TextFilter = "Test"

pt.PivotCache.Refresh
pf.ClearAllFilters
```

The below line works for exact string match:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Title").CurrentPage = TextFilter
```

The below line doesn't work for partial string match (or contains):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Title"). _
PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Test"
```

How can I set the Page filter for strings like `Test` ?

Additionally, what would be the best solution for looping the final (correct) code for other Pivot Tables within the same Worksheet and/or within the Workbook ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see documentation to explain why `PivotFilters.Add` does not work for page filters e.g. see [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/rte-1004-when-filtering-pagefield-via-macro.743298/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223012/pivottable-page-filter-filtering-with-date).

However, a simple loop does work, as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449142/update-and-filter-pivot-with-vba-wildcard-filter) that you may have seen already, but does not specify page filters.

So you can do something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim strLike As String
    
    Set pt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables(1)
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("name")
    
    strLike = "b*"
    
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True ' make sure the filter accepts multiple items
    pf.ClearManualFilter ' make sure to reset to avoid an error for no active filter
    
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (pi.Name Like strLike)
    Next pi
    
End Sub
```

To use this in a loop of all worksheets in a workbook, you can extend like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            PivotPageByWildcard pt, "name", "b*"
        Next pt
    Next ws
    
End Sub

Sub PivotPageByWildcard(pt As PivotTable, strField As String, strLike As String)

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields(strField)
    
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    pf.ClearManualFilter
    
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (pi.Name Like strLike)
    Next pi
    
End Sub
```

Simple test case:

[image]